# Why does the recursion happens again after the base call?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

So i'm trying to learn c++ and I have reached the topic of recursion and i have reached a problem.

```
void myfun(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        myfun(n-1);
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Stop"<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    myfun(n);
}`
```

The output of the program is like this:

```
stop
1
2
3
4
5
```

my question is that since the if statement is always false, how does the function calls itself in the opposite way after the base call, shouldn't the function just end?

Comment: If you pass in `5`, it will be true the first time ... and recursively, another 4 times. After your base case completes, the function _returns_ to where it was before the recursive call, which results in printing the value.

Comment: The innermost function call does return, the ones that called it are not done yet, because they haven't printed the number yet. Move `cout<<n<<endl;` before the recursive call.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that's it's "always false"?

Comment: I think i understand now, so after the base call the function returns 1 step back to where the call was made to print the value as the recursion call was now complete thus giving the values in descending order, as the function is going back to where the recursion calls were made to complete the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control flow of your main `myfun(5)` function call breaks down as (in pseudocode):

```
call myfun(5)
= [call myfun(4), print "5"]
= [[call myfun(3), print "4"], print "5"]
= [[[call myfun(2), print "3"], print "4"], print "5"]
= [[[[call myfun(1), print "2"] print "3"], print "4"], print "5"]
= [[[[[call myfun(0), print "1"], print "2"] print "3"], print "4"], print "5"]
= [[[[[[print "Stop"], print "1"], print "2"] print "3"], print "4"], print "5"]
```

where each layer of brackets represents a recursive call to `myfun`.

Since you make the recursive call *before* printing `n`, the output goes from innermost to outermost call.